# How to call meta functions in Wordpress properly

Tags: php, wordpress, function, call, meta

I am developing an author badge for my Wordpress site and I am learning how to call meta functions (needs to be within The Loop). The meta functions that I am calling are author bio related, like username, last name etc

Here is a code example:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    About <?php the_author(); ?>, the author of this blog
    <?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail() ?>
    <?php get_the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I added this example to my author.php file and it worked, however it displayed the same thing multiple times (hence the loop). How do I actually do this if I want to call meta functions in Wordpress and not have them echoed multiple times like this?

I am certain that I am doing this incorrectly and there is a correct way of achieving it.

If you choose to reply, please be detailed as my knowledge of PHP coding is to the extend that I learned what echo is *today*.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've added this to your `author.php` file, all of the posts will be by one author. So I'm guessing you want to display this content only once.

Changing your code like this will do it:

```
<?php $show_author_data = TRUE;?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if(!$show_author_data){ ?>
  About <?php the_author(); ?>, the author of this blog
  <?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail() ?>
  <?php get_the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>
<?php $show_author_data = FALSE; } ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This sets a `$show_author_data` flag for the first pass only.

Comment: I added your code to my author.php file, but it returned with **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in** . Do you know what the issue is?

Comment: Edited my code. Sorry. I didn't include the parts that didn't change.